# Angular2 in IE9 not routing?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, angular2-routing

I've setup Angular2 to use the old school HashLocationStrategy in bootstrap call:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  API_PROVIDERS, Storage,
  provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass : HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

I have set up the following routes:

```
  new Route({ path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent }),
  new Route({ path: '/search/:term/:cat/:page/:sort/:size/:more', name: 'Search6', component: HomeComponent }),
  new Route({ path: '/search/:term/:cat/:page/:sort/:size', name: 'Search5', component: HomeComponent }),
  new Route({ path: '/search/:term/:cat/:page/:sort', name: 'Search4', component: HomeComponent }),
  new Route({ path: '/search/:term/:cat/:page', name: 'Search3', component: HomeComponent }),
  new Route({ path: '/search/:term/:cat', name: 'Search2', component: HomeComponent }),
  new Route({ path: '/search/:term', name: 'Search1', component: HomeComponent }),
  new Route({ path: '/details/:accountNumber', name: 'Details', component: DetailsComponent })
```

I know my routing could be a lot cleaner if I used query string parameters instead but I'll work to clean that up later.

I construct my parameters then attempt to navigate using this line:

```
this.router.navigate(['Search' + paramCount, params]);
```

Where `paramCount` and `params` create a match with one of the routes above. This works great in Chrome, IE10, IE11, Edge, and all other browsers except for IE9 where I get no errors, no feedback of any kind and the page does not route. When I hit enter in my search box on my page it correctly builds `paramCount` and `params` and hits the navigate line above but literally nothing happens.

I'm testing in an actual IE 9 browser on Win7 (with and without Compatibility Mode which seems to make no difference). I'm on the current latest Angular2.0.0-beta15 and have every recommended shim/polyfill I can find. I also went as far back as beta 11 and none of them worked.

How can I even debug this if I get zero feedback?

Here's an absolutely minimal plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VR7SQaokPZLdfAtfyagm?p=preview

Comment: Does refreshing solve the problem? If so, it might be related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6867

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the html5 history api
   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5-history-api/4.2.7/history.min.js
before your ie.js shims file.

That is what finally worked for me and seemed to work in your plnkr.

Note: Starting in beta10, I have been having some issues with the forward/back buttons in IE9. They worked fine in IE9 in beta9.  Not sure if you will experience the same thing or not.